# Change summary text color of dialogpreference with preference V7

Tags: android, android-preferences

How can we change the text color of summary of preference. right now, its taking textcolorsecondary by default which is white color. but i dont want to use it. i want to use other color. because i need textcolorsecondary for overflow and back icon color.

you can see below image where summary text not showing because of white color.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

i just face this issue and now i find perfect solution for your problem.

**here i am going to color overflow menu using styles**. if you want to color preference summary text then use  below code.

```
 <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/white</item>
```

the solution is quite easy. **you just need to create one style(custom style)** and **use this styles in anywhere** you want to use to show overflow menu icon (vertical three dots)color.

here is my custom style code (**styles.xml**)  file :

```
 <style name="OverflowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton.Overflow">
        <item name="android:tint">#ffffff</item>
 </style>
```

and now use this style anywhere. right now i use in my main theme(which is appTheme)

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/OverflowStyle</item>
</style>
```

and for summary text of preference screen just do nothing if you want default color.

and if you want custom color then use following style attribute in your theme

```
<item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/white</item>
```

and that's it .

this will give below two results.
[image: Your overflow menu icon color]
[image: Your preference summary text color]