# How to Change text summary color on SwitchPreference

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, switchpreference

I created a Setting by using `PreferenceFragmentCompat`

```
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {

    @Override
    public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle bundle, String s) {
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings_pref);

        Preference pref = findPreference("theme_key");
        SwitchPreference swPref = (SwitchPreference) pref;

        pref.setOnPreferenceChangeListener((preference, o) -> {
            boolean state = Boolean.valueOf(o.toString());
            String summaryValue;
            if(state){
                summaryValue = swPref.getSwitchTextOn().toString();
                AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
                restartActivity();
            }else {
                summaryValue = swPref.getSwitchTextOff().toString();
                AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
                restartActivity();
            }
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Theme " + summaryValue, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        });
    }

    private void restartActivity() {
        Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), SettingsActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        getActivity().overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
        getActivity().finish();
    } }
```

and my xml file (settings_pref) looks like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <SwitchPreference
        android:key="theme_key"
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:title="@string/title_theme_pref"
        android:summaryOn="Dark"
        android:summaryOff="Light"
        android:textColor="?attr/textcolor"<!--this textColor not working, i have test with different color based on theme, still has no effect-->
        android:textColorHint="?attr/textcolor" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

as functionality it's work fine, but i still have not found literature to change Summary TextColor of my SwitchPreference which is follows current value.
Problem shows as Image like below
[image: when Dark]
[image: when Light]

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered similar problem. I scoured the internet and finally found the problem

[Change summary text color of dialogpreference with preference V7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44303757/change-summary-text-color-of-dialogpreference-with-preference-v7)

To summarize as follows:

**themes.xml**

```
    <style name="Theme.xxx.PreferenceSumary">
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/gray</item>
    </style>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<activity
            ***
            android:theme="@style/Theme.xxx.PreferenceSumary"
            *** />
```